# ASP.NET MVC does not fire jQuery Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I made similar solutions many times, so that's why I'm really surprised why this one is not working. When I click on link, this should submit data via jQuery Ajax to Controller. But instead browser just open link.

Here is Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Hide(int id)
{
    MailRepository mailRep = new MailRepository();
    var result = await mailRep.HideMail(id);
    if (result.Result == Enums.IsSuccess.Succes)
    {
        return Json(new { IsSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
        return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, DataError = result.DataError }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And here is Razor view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Hide", "Mail", new {id = a.Id})" id="hide" title="hide e-mail" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></i></a>
```

And jQuery:

```
$("#hide").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsSuccess === true) {
                $("div.alert-success").removeClass("hidden");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("div.alert-success").addClass("hidden");
                }, 5000);
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                $("#error").text(data.DataError);
                $("div.alert-warning").removeClass("hidden");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("div.alert-warning").addClass("hidden");
                }, 5000);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: how the response look like?

Comment: Your method has a parameter `int id` but your not passing anything to it

Comment: @Jai, I can't tell, as it's just open link and did not fire anything on server side.

Comment: This method accept link with parameter id something like area/controller/action/id

Comment: Pass ID to your ajax call

Comment: check your browser console. you will find error there

Comment: Perhaps there's a syntax error which prevents your handler override from binding?  Check the browser's debugger.  When you click on the link, does your handler get invoked at all?  If not, then it isn't binding to the element in the first place and has nothing to do with the AJAX code.  It *could be* something as simple as trying to bind the handler before the element exists on the page, but we can't know from the code shown.

Comment: @David, thanks. You're first who try to find reason from my problem context. And yes, this not got invoked at all.

Comment: @andrey.shedko: Then the binder isn't binding to the element.  Are you trying to bind the element before it even exists on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You are searching by an element called #hide, You need ensure that this element already exist when your jquery event is fired.

If element doesn't exist, so your jquery Ajax wont work.

Answer (score -2):

Solution are simply stupid - selector `a#hide` instead of `#hide`.

Comment: This *really* shouldn't make a difference.  If it does, that suggests to me that your markup may be re-using `id` values, which is invalid.